# Remove Slide in Jquery bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im, trying to remove the first slide after before it loops back around, I would also      like to not have the pager visible for that slide the whole time. Ive tried the onBeforeSlide callback so that it runs on the fly and then call the slider.reloadSlider() after to update the changes. I have also tried to manually call the slider.redrawSlider() but that didnt work.

The problem is that it freezes when i call the $(element).remove() on the first element as well as freezes when I call the slider.reloadSlider(). Any help would be much appreciated. My code is below.

!HTML!

```
<div id="landing-slider">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li id="first-image">
          <img class="slide-img" id="img0" src="/landing-page/S1.2.png" alt="Landing     Opening TV Image"/>
        </li>

        <li>
            <img class="slide-img" id="img1" src="/landing-page/0.png"  alt="slide image 1"/>

            <div style="font-size:16px; padding:0px 40px;">
                <p><b>1. Just enter your first name.</b></p>

                <p>Just type your first name into the box on the left this page.</p>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <img class="slide-img"  id="img2" src="/landing-page/1.png" alt="slide image 2"/>
            <div style="font-size:16px; padding:0px 40px;">
                <p><b>2. Select your best option.</b></p>

                <p>Simply select the best option for you based on your situation and what you want to
                    accomplish.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="slide-img"  id="img3" src="/landing-page/2.png" alt="slide image 3"/>

            <div style="font-size:16px; padding:0px 40px;">
                <p><b>3. Zoom throughout the process.</b></p>

                <p>Breeze through the simple, fun and exciting steps (and skip anything that isn't relevant to
                    you).</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="slide-img"  id="img4" src="/landing-page/3.png" alt="slide image 4"/>

            <div style="font-size:16px; padding:0px 40px;">
                <p><b>4. Get your personal results.</b></p>

                <p>In just minutes get complete and easy access to the best options (you may never otherwise even
                    know about) and much, much more...</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

!Javascript!

```
  var landingSlider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
       pager: true,
       auto: true,
       autoControls: true,
       pause: 1500,
       onSlideBefore: function($elment, oldIndex, newIndex){
         if($elment.is($("#first-image"))){
             $("#first-image").remove();
             landingSlider.reloadSlider();
             landingSlider.redrawSlider();
         }
       },
       onSlideAfter: function() {
           $('.bx-start').trigger('click');
       }
   });
```

Comment: I recommend you the http://www.awkwardgroup.com/sandbox/awkward-showcase-a-jquery-plugin/

Comment: And this provides functionality for dynamically remove slides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit obscene but maybe something like (assuming your pause is 1500 as above, set the timeout for just after the first slide has finished)

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#first-image').remove();
},2000);
```

Place this anywhere in `$(document).ready(function(){` but outside the `bxslider()` bit

Comment: Awesome that worked thanks! Why wasn't this working inside the bxslider callback? what made it obscene? keen to learn :):)

Comment: do you have s JSFiddle ?, please answer the question from @Josh.S comment.

Comment: Fantastic. Absolutely no idea why it failed. Just a punt really.

Comment: Nope. Its a giant mess with heavily modified CSS, I seem to have it working though thanks @FranciscoCorrales

Comment: @dwhite.me I fixed it with the below post. Much better solution.

Comment: Obscene because it doesn't deal with the plugin's native functionality, just a lazy answer that would most certainly have worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the answer was the my callback didn't reset the settings of the slider so it was set to default and the slide stop automatically transitioning. I made a settings object and reloaded it with those settings after the first slide was removed.

```
       var timeBetweenSlides = 4000;
       var timeToChangeSlide = 500;
       var landingSliderSettings = {
           startSlide: 0,
           speed: timeToChangeSlide,
           pause: timeBetweenSlides,
           pager: true,
           auto: true,
           autoControls: true,
           onSlideAfter: function() {
               $('.bx-start').trigger('click');
           },
           onSlideBefore: function($elment, oldIndex, newIndex){
               if($elment.is($("#first-image"))){
                   $("#first-image").remove();
                   landingSlider.reloadSlider(landingSliderSettings);
               }
           }
       }
       var landingSlider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider(landingSliderSettings);
```